# Get Distinct list of two properties using MongoDB 2.4

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an article collection:

```
{
    _id: 9999,
    authorId: 12345,
    coAuthors: [23456,34567],
    title: 'My Article'
},
{
    _id: 10000,
    authorId: 78910,
    title: 'My Second Article'
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get a list of distinct author and co-author ids out of the database. I have tried `push`, `concat`, and `addToSet`, but can't seem to find the right combination. I'm on 2.4.6 so I don't have access to `setUnion`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst [**`$setUnion`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) would be the "ideal" way to do this, there is another way that basically involved "switching" between a "type" to alternate which field is picked:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "authorId": 1,
        "coAuthors": { "$ifNull": [ "$coAuthors", [null] ] },
        "type": { "$const": [ true,false ] }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$coAuthors" },
    { "$unwind": "$type" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "$cond": [
                 "$type",
                 "$authorId",
                 "$coAuthors"
            ]
        }
    }},
    { "$match": { "_id": { "$ne": null } } }
])
```

And that is it. You may know the `$const` operation as the [**`$literal`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/) operator from MongoDB 2.6. It has always been there, but was only documented and given an "alias" at the 2.6 release.

Of course the `$unwind` operations in both cases produce more "copies" of the data, but this is grouping for "distinct" values so it does not matter. Just depending on the `true/false` alternating value for the projected "type" field ( once unwound ) you just pick the field alternately.

Also this little mapReduce does much the same thing:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
  function() {
    emit(this.authorId,null);
    if ( this.hasOwnProperty("coAuthors"))
      this.coAuthors.forEach(function(id) { 
        emit(id,null);
      });
  },
  function(key,values) {
    return null;
  },
  { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

For the record, `$setUnion` is of course a lot cleaner and more performant:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "combined": { 
            "$setUnion": [
                { "$map": {
                    "input": ["A"],
                    "as": "el",
                    "in": "$authorId"
                }},
                { "$ifNull": [ "$coAuthors", [] ] }
            ]
        }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$combined" },
    { "$group": {
      "_id": "$combined"
    }}
])
```

So there the only real concerns are converting the singular "authorId" to an array via [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and feeding an empty array where the "coAuthors" field is not present in the document.

Both output the same distinct values from the sample documents:

```js
{ "_id" : 78910 }
{ "_id" : 23456 }
{ "_id" : 34567 }
{ "_id" : 12345 }
```